# Change input type with vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have an input, how can I change it's type based on a condition?

```
<input :type="showInput ? text : hidden">
```

I've tried the above and type does not render.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Are `text` and `hidden` variables? If not, you need to set the value of type to a string:

```
<input :type="showInput ? 'text' : 'hidden'">
```